# How to add mongodb db connection url in auth0?

Tags: mongodb, auth0, mongodb-atlas

I have some problem with auth0 custom db connection.
Here is code(it's auth0 template):

```
function create (user, callback) {
  mongo('mongodb://user:pass@mymongoserver.com/my-db', function (db) {
    var users = db.collection('users');

    users.findOne({ email: user.email }, function (err, withSameMail) {

      if (err) return callback(err);
      if (withSameMail) return callback(new Error('the user already exists'));

      bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) { return callback(err); }
        user.password = hash;
        users.insert(user, function (err, inserted) {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          callback(null);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I use MongoDB Atlas as db and I don't know how to connect this database to auth0 because when I'm trying to put Atlas url like this

```
"mongodb://kay:myRealPassword@mycluster0-shard-00-00.mongodb.net:27017,mycluster0-shard-00-01.mongodb.net:27017,mycluster0-shard-00-02.mongodb.net:27017/admin?ssl=true&replicaSet=Mycluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin"
```

Auth0 throws me this error:

```
[Error] Error: Client request error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:213:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:305:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:923:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:511:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:466:17)
```

And when I'm using url like this one:

```
mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/test
```

It throws me something like that:

```
[SandboxUnhandledError] unknown mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/test config
```

Please help me because I don't know what to do.
P.S. I add auth0 IP addresses to MongoDB Atlas whitelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclosure, I work for Auth0.

I believe this might be an issue with a legacy driver. The global in `mongo` is currently to preserve legacy scripts. Your new Rules / Custom DBs should `require` an explicit version of the `mongo` driver and rely on it. Such as

`var mongo = require('mongo');`

or even more explicitely

`var mongo = require('mongo@x.y.z');`

A complete list of all modules available in Rules / Custom DB scripts is at https://tehsis.github.io/webtaskio-canirequire/

Comment: When I'm trying to use MongoClient like require('mongodb@version').MongoClient and then making connection there throws another error: Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Comment: As per the docs the function will be called as `err, db` the first argument will be `error` which is `null`. Please refer to the https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native docs